# Keystone cant hide x-powered-by

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I'm trying to remove both node.js and express x-powered-by with expressjs commands but they don't work.

Here are the commands that I'm using both where working on other projects

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

or

```
app.set('x-powered-by', false);
```

Is there another way to do this in keystonejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i have found a solution to this
Instead of using it at the keystone.js you must use it on the routes - middleware

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var middleware = require('./middleware');
var importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);

// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views'),
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views
    app.set('x-powered-by', false);//<<< Place it here
    app.get('/', routes.views.news);
};
```